# Current snow depth in Tromsø

Tags: online-resources, weather-and-climate, norway, snow, tromso

I'm going to Tromsø, Norway and am concerned about the snow depth and how it will affect my ability to get around - how can I find out where to get the current depth online?

Comment: I accidentally discovered the website [webcams.travel](http://www.webcams.travel/) while looking at the yr.no page, and it turned out to be a quick and easy way to see what's the weather like at the moment in the location that interests you.

Comment: Get around where? The city? If you are worried about the city, I where there 2 years ago and there is no snow in the streets, but sometimes you can find some ice.

Comment: What Ivan said. You can walk anywhere that the locals might go, snow is cleared away, but if you want to go wandering around the countryside you'll need skis.

Comment: well im going to photograph the northern lights, skis you say? *gulp*.

Comment: I found with Stockholm that there was still snow in th city, 25cm or so. which wasn't annoying, but did slow me down a little more than I expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Senorge.no](http://www.senorge.no/index.html?p=senorge&st=snow) has complete snowdepth information for the entire territory of Norway.  They have both present and historical information.

Currently, 8 August 2013, there is not much snow:

[image: Screenshow senorge.no]

However, it's also possible to obtain historical data, for example, from 1 June 2012:

[image: Screenshow senorge.no]

Or, indeed, from 24 January 2012:

[image]

If you want to go skiing to mountain summits, June may be a better time than January.

Answer (score 7):

The Norwegian website [yr.no](http://www.yr.no/) is a good resource for weather information in Scandinavia. Looking at the information about [Tromsø](http://www.yr.no/sted/Norge/Troms/Troms%C3%B8/Troms%C3%B8/), among other things, there are live webcams on the bottom of the page, which, sadly, show that there is currently no snow at all there.

Direct link to the webcams: [here](http://www.thorheim.no/webkamera_tromso.asp) and [here](http://ekstra.htg.no/webcam/TF_tromso.html). See also [detailed weather information](http://www.thorheim.no/vaeret_tromso.asp), together with rain/snowfall in mm (middle graphs, named Nedbør).

Comment: Another excellent webcam is at the [UiT CS department](http://weather.cs.uit.no/).  It includes archives and even time-lapse videos per past month or year, great fun to watch (: