# Where can I find out the current snow depth in Iceland?

Tags: online-resources, iceland, weather-and-climate, snow

Is there a website that reports the current snow depth across Iceland? I'm after a site with similar detail to the question in [this answer about Norway](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/19551/449).

Comment: Related Question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11537/what-is-the-most-accurate-snow-report-website

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several sites that offer this information including those for Ski Resorts.

- [Snow Forecast](http://www.snow-forecast.com/maps/dynamic/iceland)
- [Ski Resort](http://www.skiresort.info/snow-reports/europe/iceland/)